# Get Highest and lowest value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array:

```
var data = [{
            // series 1
            data: [ [1, 30], [2, 40],[3, 38], [4, 39], [5, 42]                    ],
            color: '#8bc12c', 
                        points: { radius: 4, fillColor: '#8bc12c' }
            }, 
            {
                // series 2
                data: [ [1, 30], [2, 40],[3, 38], [4, 39], [5, 42]              ],
                color: '#858585',
                points: { radius: 4, fillColor: '#858585' }
            },
            {
                // series 3
                data: [ [1, 30], [2, 40],[3, 38], [4, 39], [5, 42]                       ],
                color: '#e88278',
                points: { radius: 4, fillColor: '#e88278' }
            }, 
                        {
                // series 4
                data: [ [1, 50], [2, 60],[3, 58], [4, 59], [5, 62]                    ],
                color: '#5a5a5a',
                points: { radius: 4, fillColor: '#5a5a5a' }
            }

        ];
```

I would like to get the data contains another array of data which has [x,y] values.  How do I get the highest y value out of this array? Which in this case would be 62

Comment: Hint: `$.each` or `$.map`

Comment: You can simply iterate over the elements of the array and compare each y value to the currently largest one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var max = 0 ;

$.each(data,function(){
    $.each(this.data,function(i,v){
        if(v[1] > max){
          max = v[1];
        }
    })
})

console.log("max : " + max);
```

Comment: @FelixKling someone removed the `jQuery` tag from the post.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer it was me because i think such tasks may be solved without jQuery

Comment: @Igor: But it indicates that jQuery solutions are acceptable as well. The `javascript` tag description says *" A pure JavaScript answer is usually expected, except if a tag for a framework or library is also present."* I'm all for pure JavaScript solutions though.

Comment: With Underscore var maxmax;
var max1 =  _.max(data1, function(d){.
    return  _.max(d.data, function(d1){.
     maxmax = d1[1];return maxmax;
    } )[1];
});

console.log(maxmax);

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate one-liner:

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, data.map(function(o) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, o.data.map(function(o) {
    return o[1];
  }));
})));
```

Comment: Note that [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is ES5.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Yep, I leave the [shims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) to OP :)